# Merge 2 files with awk while keeping all columns and add extra column based on match in column 1

Tags: awk

I have 2 files with thousands of lines. The first column in each file are populated with IP addresses. I would like to merge the two files keeping all columns from both files, written to a third file. I would also like to add a header to the file. To make it even harder... If an IP in file 1 is in file 2 then just merge those lines, if not then merge the lines and add a new column with "add" in it, but If an IP in file 2 does not match file 1 then add "delete" to the new column.

file 1 scanner output

```
Column 1    Column 2   Column 3  column 4  
10.1.10.5   nuts.com   2214.53   9/19/2014   
10.1.10.8   sites.net  7233.55   10/24/2010  
10.1.25.6              7611.76   1/24/2010  
10.1.25.7   nobb.com   000.00    9/19/2010
```

file 2 internal ip list

```
Column 1    Column 2  
10.1.10.2   001 T & R  
10.1.10.3   001 T & R  
10.1.25.6   022 office  
10.1.25.7   022 office
```

Desired Output
File 3

```
Column 1    Column 2     Column 3   column 4     column 5     column 6    
10.1.10.2                                        001 T & R    add      
10.1.10.3                                        001 T & R    add   
10.1.10.5   nuts.com     2214.53    9/19/2014                delete    
10.1.10.8   sites.net    7233.55    10/24/2010               delete    
10.1.25.6                7611.76    1/24/2010    022 office      
10.1.25.7   nobb.com     000.00     9/19/2010    022 office
```

I've gotten as far as this

```
 awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} !($1 in a) {$5="Delete"}1 ' OFS="," ipinput.csv scaninput.csv
```

but I can't seem to get all columns listed with the added column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following awk script can help you

```
 awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} NR==FNR{ip[$1]=$2"|"$3"|"$4} NR!=FNR{if ( $1 in ip) {  print $1,ip[$1],$2,"null"; delete ip[$1];} else print  $1,"null|null|null",$2,"add" } END{for ( i in ip ) print i, ip[i],"delete" } '
```

gives output as

```
10.1.10.2 |null|null|null| 001 T & R|add
10.1.10.3 |null|null|null| 001 T & R|add
10.1.25.6 | null field | 7611.76 | 1/24/2010| 022 office|null
10.1.25.7 | nobb.com | 000.00 | 9/19/2010| 022 office|null
10.1.10.5 | nuts.com | 2214.53 |9/19/2014|delete
10.1.10.8 | sites.net | 7233.55 |10/24/2010|delete
```

Comment: Sorry my example is very confusing and not structured well but, I put the pipes "|" in there to show the different columns and null fields can just be blanks in the csv output. Column A = IP, Column B = dns, Column C = score, Column D = date, Column E = office, Column F = status

Comment: I added ipinput.csv scaninput.csv > test2.csv to the end of the script and ran it but got the date, status, and a bunch of |'s and null's, all in Column D. I also get duplicates for 10.1.25.6 and 10.1.25.7 .

Comment: @DannyBlack glad to hear it worked. sorry that i couldnt correct the answer latter on

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=",";print "IP Address","HostName","Vuln Score","Date","Department","Status";} NR==FNR{ip[$1]=$2","$3","$4} NR!=FNR{if ($1 in ip) {  print $1,ip[$1],$2; delete ip[$1];} else print  $1,"\t","\t","\t",$2,"add"; delete ip[$1];} END{for (i in ip) print i,ip[i],"\t","delete"} '  scanoutput.csv ipoutput.csv  > test3.csv
```

Using the great example from nu11p01n73R, I modified it a little to get what I need. Also, I wanted to get it on the site just in case it helps anyone else. Thanks again.

Output

```
IP Address  HostName   Vuln Score    Date       Department  Status    
10.1.10.2                                        001 T & R    add      
10.1.10.3                                        001 T & R    add   
10.1.25.6                7611.76    1/24/2010    022 office      
10.1.25.7   nobb.com     000.00     9/19/2010    022 office
10.1.10.5   nuts.com     2214.53    9/19/2014                delete    
10.1.10.8   sites.net    7233.55    10/24/2010               delete
```